# What is blockchain in simplest terms for Web app developer ? What can I use it for?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum

I have background of web-applications, enterprise applications. With that context; where do I fit blockchain ! What is it in most simplest terms !

Comment: Way too broad and your answer isn't even close to answering this properly.

Comment: I agree.. This answer is for someone to create an analogy with what we know to what we are learning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most simplest terms; to start with think of block-chain as a distributed database.. Probably something like NoSQL...

Just like we have many NoSQL databases; we have many block chain implementations like Ethereum, Ripple, Hyperledger.

Just like we can create infinite applications using NoSQL databases; similarly we can do using blockchain in almost all domains.. BitCoin is just most successful application developed on blockchain. As we know any application can be developed in most technologies; but still every one has pros and cons and more suited for particular use cases .. The target markets for Blockchain are mostly banks and other Financial Institutions.

Best part is that block-chain is NOT just a highly secured, distributed database which is owned by many companies.. but it has many more advanced concepts like Smart Contracts ( something like Serverless pieces of code which can run independently )..

I am not saying this is complete explanation. You can anyway find lots of stuff on internet.. This is to keep thing overly simple ( which causes some of not correct/incomplete info )

Answer (score 5):

Well, you are a web developer with background in centralized web-applications, this is how they work at a very high level:

[image: centralized]

You can see the apps are hosted *somewhere*, which is basically a server at some hoster. This server is a central instance serving the content of your web application and processing the logic.

Your clients use a web browser to access this content by entering your public web address into their browser. This is resolved by a centralized DNS (domain name service) and points to your server.

---

Decentralized applications (DApps) on Ethereum look quite different, here is how, again at high level:

[image: decentralized]

You can see that the client experience is similar, the users utilizes a browser to access an web application and in most cases hardly notices that there is something *different*.

The difference, however, is the content is not served from any server but from a decentralized peer-to-peer networks. All HTML, JS, CSS and content files are served from decentralized storage solutions like [IPFS](https://ipfs.io/) or [Swarm](http://swarm-gateways.net/). Important program logic is executed at the blockchain (in the Ethereum Virtual Machine - EVM) which works like a immutable registrar to verify hashes and to lookup tables of data (similar to a database) and execute strongly typed smart contracts. Instead of an DNS there is a decentralized name registrar called [Ethereum Name Service - ENS](http://ens.domains/) which is a smart contract allowing to register `.eth` domains for the use with decentralized applications.

Not sure if the terms are simple enough, please let me know if the traditional web 2.0 analogy works out for you. [Image credit and further reading](https://medium.com/@mvmurthy/ethereum-for-web-developers-890be23d1d0c).

Answer (score 4):

Blockchain, a secure distributed ledger (data structure or database) that maintains a continuously growing list of ordered records, called “blocks.”Please watch this youtube video - [Blockchain 101 - A Visual Demo](https://youtu.be/_160oMzblY8) to understand the basics of Blockchain.
That is a very basic visual introduction to the concepts behind a blockchain. He introduces the idea of an immutable ledger using an interactive web demo. If you are interested in playing with this on your own, it is available online at:https://github.com/anders94/blockchain-demo

Blockchain was originally developed as the technology behind cryptocurrencies like Bitcoin. A vast, globally distributed ledger running on millions of devices, it is capable of recording anything of value. Money, equities, bonds, titles, deeds, contracts, and virtually all other kinds of assets can be moved and stored securely, privately, and from peer to peer, because trust is established not by powerful intermediaries like banks and governments, but by network consensus, cryptography, collaboration, and clever code.You can learn more about Blockchain use cases from [this TED talk](https://www.ted.com/talks/don_tapscott_how_the_blockchain_is_changing_money_and_business?utm_source=tedcomshare&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=tedspread).

Ethereum, a type of blockchain that can be used to develop decentralized applications &  several banks have already adapted Ethereum to develop and test blockchain trading applications. The Ethereum blockchain was developed by a Canadian named Vitalik Buterin and this blockchain has some extraordinary capabilities. One of them is that you can build smart contracts. It's kind of what it sounds like. It's a contract that self-executes, and the contract handles the enforcement, the management, performance and payment — the contract kind of has a bank account, too, in a sense — of agreements between people.Also, JPMorgan Chase & Co, Microsoft, Intel, and more than two dozen other companies have teamed up to develop standards and technology to make it easier for enterprises to Ethereum.

Truffle is a development environment, testing framework and asset pipeline for Ethereum, aiming to make life as an Ethereum developer easier. With Truffle, you get:

- Built-in smart contract compilation, linking, deployment and binary management.
- Automated contract testing with Mocha and Chai.
- Configurable build pipeline with support for custom build processes.
- Scriptable deployment & migrations framework.
- Network management for deploying to many public & private networks.
- Interactive console for direct contract communication.
- Instant rebuilding of assets during development.
- External script runner that executes scripts within a Truffle environment.

You can find a great sample project here:https://github.com/tomw1808/truffle_eth_class1

You can find really good courses on Building A Decentralised Blockchain Application in Udemy.Please message me,if you need any further information.

Answer (score -1):

Blockchain in simple words, it is the latest technology idea for cryptocurrencies like Bitcoin. For example, the bitcoin will have its value in the market as is, and you will be able to use it to pay for daily life needs such as taking an uber ride, or buying from the corner store groceries. Basically, the state of cash or money as paper will disappear and that's the idea behind it. You could ask why, answer, there are more than answer for this and the reasons of coming up with the idea is big. Therefore, I just explained it in simple words. read about it more if you need to know about it more. Hope this is helpful.